# Converting a json format timestamp to golangs time.Time

Tags: string, go, time

I have a datetime string in json with the below format

```
 /Date(315513000000+0530)/
```

I would like to convert this into golangs `time.Time` format. I tried passing this string to the below function

```
func parseDateField(dateInput string) (int64, error) {
    startIdx := strings.Index(dateInput, "(")
    if startIdx == -1 {
        return 0, errors.New("Error parsing quote Date. '(' symbol not found")
    }

    endIdx := strings.Index(dateInput, "+")
    if endIdx == -1 {
    return 0, errors.New("Error parsing quote Date. '+' symbol not found")
     }
    dateStr := dateInput[startIdx+1 : endIdx]
    date, err := strconv.ParseInt(dateStr, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(" err : \n %+v \n", err)
        return 0, err
     }
     tm := time.Unix(date, 0)
     fmt.Printf("\n time  : \n %+v \n", tm)
     dateAsEpoch := int64(date / 1000)
     fmt.Printf("\n dateAsEpoch  : \n %+v \n", dateAsEpoch)
     return dateAsEpoch, nil
}
```

I'm getting the below outputs

```
 time  : 
 11968-03-18 01:30:00 +0530 IST 


 dateAsEpoch  : 
 315513000
```

I'm guessing the parsing isnt done right - what am i doing wrong?

Comment: wait, what is the right date? what kind of format is this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/1246282

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That time format seems to be the elapsed milliseconds since epoch and a signed 4-digit zone offset (hour and min).

Easiest would be to use [`fmt.Sscanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf) to parse it, something like this:

```
_, err = fmt.Sscanf(s, "/Date(%d+%02d%02d)/", &ms, &zoneHour, &zoneMin)
```

Of course if the zone offset is negative, the format will not match. That can be handled by a second attempt of parsing, `+` replaced by a `-` in the format string.

Once you have the `ms`, multiply it by a million to get nanoseconds, so you can pass that to [`time.Unix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) (it is valid to pass a nanoseconds value outside of the `[0, 999999999]` range).

Last you can use [`time.FixedZone()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#FixedZone) to obtain a zone corresponding to the zone offset in the input, and then use [`Time.In()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In) to "switch over" to this zone.

<sup>Note that the milliseconds since epoch is zone-independent (it is given in UTC zone). Switching over to the source's zone offset is only required so that when you print the time (or you access its "fields" like year, month, day), you will see the intended date and time, as that would be different in another zone. For example the instance you have, it designates the date `1980-01-01` and 0 time in the day. Without the `+0530` zone, that would be a different day, it would be `1979-12-31 18:30:00 +0000 UTC`.</sup>

Here's an example doing it:

```
func parse(s string) (t time.Time, err error) {
    var ms int64
    var zhour, zmin int

    if _, err = fmt.Sscanf(s, "/Date(%d+%02d%02d)/", &ms, &zhour, &zmin); err != nil {
        if _, err = fmt.Sscanf(s, "/Date(%d-%02d%02d)/", &ms, &zhour, &zmin); err != nil {
            return time.Time{}, fmt.Errorf("Failed to parse: %v", err)
        }
        zhour = -zhour
        zmin = -zmin
    }

    t = time.Unix(0, ms*1000000)
    t = t.In(time.FixedZone("", zhour*3600+zmin*60))
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(parse("/Date(315513000000+0530)/"))
fmt.Println(parse("/Date(315513000000-0530)/"))
fmt.Println(parse("invalid"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QTMa4nEKGt-)):

```
1980-01-01 00:00:00 +0530 +0530 <nil>
1979-12-31 13:00:00 -0530 -0530 <nil>
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Failed to parse: input does not match format
```